# PHPMail always sending when page is refreshed

Tags: php

I have a code that send an email but how I can prevent it from always sending everytime my page refreshes. I tried using the `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {}` so that mail sending will just be triggered when `Submit` button is clicked but it did not help at all.

```
function two_dim_array_to_html_table($arr, $colcomments){
    $ret = "<table border='1' width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' align='center'>\n";
$ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach($arr[0] as $key => $val){
        $ret .= "\t\t<th>".$colcomments[$key]."</th>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
    foreach($arr as $row){
        $ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $column){
            $ret .= "\t\t<td>".$column."</td>\n";
            }
        $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "<table>\n";
    return $ret;
    }
    if($result) {
        $Body = "<html>\n"
            . "<head>\n"
. "</head>\n"
            . "<body>\n"
. two_dim_array_to_html_table($result, $colcomments)
            . "</body>\n"
. "</html>\n";
//Setting up Mail
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            //useful for debugging, shows full SMTP errors
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
            // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            // Enable encryption, usually SSL/TLS
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            // Specify host server
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }
        $mail->From = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
        $mail->FromName = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        $mail->AddAddress('test.test@domain.COM');
        $mail->Subject = 'Daily Tasks - "'.date('d-m-Y h:m:s').'"';
        $mail->WordWrap = 100;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $Body;
        $mail->Send();
    }
```

I tried using this but it does not seem to work,

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by just adding another button for send mail and use,

```
if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])){
//EMAIL function
if($mail) {
    echo 'Mail successfully sent';

} else {

    echo 'Mail failed to send';
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your "mail" code in a function and call the function when the form has been submitted. This way u are sure that the mail will only be send when u submit your form.